# Slow binary data writing on an old Android device

Tags: android-file

I wonder if anyone could offer any suggestions to improve the performance of binary data writing on an old enterprise Android 5.1 device.

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileDescriptor);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
byte[] abData = new byte[1024*1024];
long lStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
for(int i= 0; i < 30; i++){
    bos.write(abData);
}
long lDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - lStart;
utility.logDebug("OEDebug: duration (MS): " + lDuration);
```

The execution of the above testing code to write 30MB data takes about 1.2 seconds. If FileOutputStream is used directly instead of the BufferedOutputStream, the outcome is virtually the same. We deal with files with sizes of hundreds of MB. Writing them takes well over 10 seconds each. Is there anything that I can try to improve the speed?

Answer (score 1):

Improving the performance of binary data writing on an old Android 5.1 device can be challenging due to hardware limitations and the age of the operating system. However, there are several strategies you can try to optimize the writing process:

1. Increase Buffer Size: The default buffer size might not be optimal
   for your use case. Try increasing the size of the buffer in
   BufferedOutputStream to see if it improves performance. Experiment
   with different sizes to find the best fit.
2. Use Direct I/O: If your device supports it, using direct I/O can
   bypass the OS cache and write directly to disk. This can be faster
   for large files, though it may not be supported on all devices or
   file systems.
3. Optimize Disk Access Patterns: Writing large chunks of data at once
   can be more efficient than writing many smaller chunks. If possible,
   try to organize your data so that you can write large contiguous
   blocks.
4. Avoid Frequent Disk Writes: If your application logic allows,
   accumulate data in memory and write it in bulk to the disk less
   frequently. This can reduce the overhead associated with disk I/O
   operations.

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

try {
    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileDescriptor);
    
    // Increased buffer size for performance improvement
    int bufferSize = 8 * 1024 * 1024; // 8 MB
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream, bufferSize);
    
    byte[] abData = new byte[1024 * 1024]; // 1 MB
    long lStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        bos.write(abData);
    }

    long lDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - lStart;
    utility.logDebug("OEDebug: duration (MS): " + lDuration);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle exceptions appropriately
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (bos != null) {
            bos.close();
        }
        if (fileOutputStream != null) {
            fileOutputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. Buffer Size: I've increased the buffer size to 8 MB. You should
   experiment with this value to find the optimal size for your
   specific use case.
2. Exception Handling: The code now includes proper exception handling
   and ensures that the streams are closed in the finally block.
3. Asynchronous Writing: To implement asynchronous writing, you would
   need to move the writing logic to a separate thread. This can be
   done using AsyncTask, Thread, or other concurrency tools in Android,
   but it's more complex and depends on the overall structure of your
   application.